# Calculating skewness of a data distribution in SQL in Access without an additional subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, statistics, skew

I have a dataset in an Access database that, for simplicity's sake, looks like this:

```
      ID     Group   Employee       Ticket ID
    ------ --------- -------- -----------------
      1        A       Joe           123414
      2        A       Joe           12309124
      3        A       Bob           112321321
      4        A       Bob           213123214142
      5        A       Sam           123214214124
      6        B       Jen           412949218419
      7        B       Amy           12341234213
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate the [statistical skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) of distribution of the number of tickets each employee has handled.

In a perfect world, my SQL would be this:

```sql
SELECT
    [Group], SKEW([myCount]) AS mySkew
FROM
    (
     SELECT [Group], [Employee], COUNT(*) AS myCount
     FROM MyTable
     GROUP BY [Group], [Employee]
    )
        AS TempTable
GROUP BY
   [Group];
```

However, it appears that Access does not have a `SKEW` function.  Anyone know how I can do this calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like somebody has tried this and created a small library for it here:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS_Access/A_2529-Median-Mode-Skewness-and-Kurtosis-in-MS-Access.html

Comment: Thanks, but given that I already have a subquery in here, it looks like it's going to become ridiculously complicated.

Comment: There has to be a better way.  This is such an obvious thing to be missing.

Comment: The code in the cited article does not seem that difficult or complicated to **use**; you are asking for a complicated thing, especially for a derived value.  Try modifying the example labeled "Skewness and kurtosis by Code".

Comment: This is for TransactSQL and does require other subqueries: https://sqlwithpanks.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/skewness-a-measure-of-asymmetry-using-tsql/comment-page-1/