# Query and/or function that subsets the data on one field for all types and calcs on other field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, subquery, aggregate-functions

I am trying to go from this:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| fld1 | fld2 | fld3 | etc… |
+------+------+------+------+
| a    |    5 |    1 |      |
| b    |    5 |    0 |      |
| c    |    6 |    0 |      |
| b    |    2 |    5 |      |
| b    |    1 |    6 |      |
| c    |    0 |    6 |      |
| a    |    8 |    9 |      |
+------+------+------+------+
```

To:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+-----+-----+------+
| Factor |  Agg   | CalcDate  | Sum | Avg | etc… |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----+-----+------+
| fld2   | fld1/a | 8/14/2015 |  13 | 6.5 |      |
| fld2   | fld1/b | 8/14/2015 |   8 | 2.7 |      |
| fld2   | fld1/c | 8/14/2015 |   6 | 3   |      |
| fld3   | fld1/a | 8/14/2015 |  10 | 5   |      |
| fld3   | fld1/b | 8/14/2015 |  11 | 3.7 |      |
| fld3   | fld1/c | 8/14/2015 |   6 | 3   |      |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----+-----+------+
```

Notes:

- Obviously this data is simplified quite a bit.
- I have a ton of fields I need to do this for
- I included easy aggregation calcs here so it might be easier for someone to help me. The exhaustive list is: NaPct, Mean, Sd, Low, Q1, Median, Q3, High, IQR, Kurt, Skew, Obs. Where NaPct = Percent that are NULL, Sd = Standard deviation, Q1 = quartile 1, Q3 = quartile 3, IQR = Inter quartile range, Kurt = Kurtosis, Skew = Skewness, Obs = number of observations that are not NULL.
- In reality, in the second table above the factor field will be FactorID, Agg will be AggID, and CalcDate will be CalcDateID, but I put the actual values in there for illustration purposes. Shouldn't matter to the question/answer though.
- Speed is very important as I have 1305 fields and several aggregations to do calculations on before the work day starts.
- Answers using only MS Access, SQL, and VBA. Sorry business requirement. That said, a SQL only answer that works in MS Access would be best for simplicity.
- Below is code that uses a custom domain function (DCalcForQueries) and supporting functions that I built that return one calculated aggregate value per field and selected aggregation. Aka, not what I want. Maybe that code is usable for what I want, maybe not. Nevertheless it has the calculations I want in it which hopefully will help.
- The message boxes are just how I debug while I am alpha testing: not necessary.
- To use the code, put all of the code in a VBA module, change table "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" to a table you have in MS Access, change field "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" to a field in your table, and run the TestIT() sub and you should get calculated values in the Immediate window.
- Don't worry about the calculations so much. I'll deal with that. I just need to know what is the best way to get from the first table above to the second table above in a way that allows for the calculations that I want. Thanks!

  ```
  Sub TestIt()
  Dim x
  Set x = GetOrOpenAndGetExcel

  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim sSql As String
  Dim q As String
  q = VBA.Chr(34)
  sSql = "SELECT " & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "NaPct" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS NaPct ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Mean" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Mean ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Sd" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Sd ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Low" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Low ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Q1" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Q1 ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Median" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Median ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Q3" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Q3 ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "High" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS High ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "IQR" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS IQR ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Kurt" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Kurt ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Skew" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Skew ," & _
              "DCalcForQueries(" & q & "Obs" & q & ", " & q & "tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0" & q & ", " & q & "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" & q & ", " & q & "[Rk-IU Mkt Cap] IS NOT NULL AND [GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'" & q & ") AS Obs " & _
              "FROM tbl_DatedModel_2015_0702_0;"
  Debug.Print sSql
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSql, dbOpenSnapshot)
  rst.MoveFirst

  Debug.Print rst.RecordCount
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("NaPct")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Mean")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Sd")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Low")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Q1")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Median")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Q3")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("High")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("IQR")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Kurt")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Skew")
  Debug.Print rst.Fields("Obs")


  End Sub
  Public Function DCalcForQueries(sCalc As String, Optional sTbl As String = "", Optional sMainFld As String = "", Optional sWhereClause As String = "", Optional k As Double) As Variant

  Dim dblData() As Double
  Dim oxl As Object
  On Error Resume Next
  Set oxl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Excel object must be openned by the calling sub of DCalcForQueries so it isn't opened over and over, which is very slow"
      GoTo cleanup
  End If

  Dim x As Integer

  Dim aV() As Variant
  Dim tmp
  Dim lObsCnt As Long
  Dim lNaCnt As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim vTmp As Variant
  Dim lTtl As Long
  Dim bDoCalc As Boolean

  aV = a2dvGetSubsetFromQuery(sTbl, sMainFld, sWhereClause, "Numeric")
  If aV(0, 0) = "Not Numeric" Then
      MsgBox "Data returned by query was not numeric. Press OK to Stop and debug."
      Stop
  End If

  If sCalc = "Percentile" Or sCalc = "Q1" Or sCalc = "Q2" Or sCalc = "Q3" Or sCalc = "Q4" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Exc(aV, k)
  ElseIf sCalc = "Median" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.Median(aV)
  ElseIf sCalc = "Kurt" Or sCalc = "Kurt" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.Kurt(aV)
  ElseIf sCalc = "Minimum" Or sCalc = "Low" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.Min(aV)
  ElseIf sCalc = "Maximum" Or sCalc = "High" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.Max(aV)
  ElseIf sCalc = "IQR" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.Quartile_Exc(aV, 3) - oxl.WorksheetFunction.Quartile_Exc(aV, 1)
  ElseIf sCalc = "Obs" Then
      lObsCnt = 0
      For Each tmp In aV
          If Not IsNull(tmp) Then
              lObsCnt = lObsCnt + 1
          End If
      Next
      DCalcForQueries = lObsCnt
  ElseIf sCalc = "%NA" Or sCalc = "PctNa" Or sCalc = "NaPct" Or sCalc = "%Null" Or sCalc = "PctNull" Then
      lNaCnt = 0
      lTtl = UBound(aV, 2) + 1
      For Each tmp In aV
          If IsNull(tmp) Then
              lNaCnt = lNaCnt + 1
          End If
      Next
      DCalcForQueries = (lNaCnt / lTtl) * 100
  ElseIf sCalc = "Skewness" Or sCalc = "Skew" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.Skew(aV)
  ElseIf sCalc = "StDev" Or sCalc = "Sd" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(aV)
  ElseIf sCalc = "Mean" Then
      DCalcForQueries = oxl.WorksheetFunction.Average(aV)
  Else
      MsgBox "sCalc parameter not recognized: " & sCalc
  End If

  cleanup:


  End Function

  Function a2dvGetSubsetFromQuery(sTbl As String, sMainFld As String, sWhereClause As String, sTest As String) As Variant()
  'sTest can be  "Numeric" or "None" ...will implement more as needed
  Dim iFieldType As Integer
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim db As Database
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Dim sMainFldFull As String
  Dim sSubSetFldFull As String
  Dim sSql As String

  sMainFldFull = "[" & sMainFld & "]"
  sSubSetFldFull = ""
  sSql = ""

  sSql = "SELECT " & sMainFldFull & " FROM " & sTbl
  If Len(sWhereClause) > 0 Then
      sSql = sSql & " WHERE " & sWhereClause
  End If

  Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sSql, dbOpenSnapshot)

  'make sure the data is the right type

  iFieldType = rst(sMainFld).Type

  If sTest = "Numeric" Then
      If iFieldType = dbByte Or _
          iFieldType = dbInteger Or _
          iFieldType = dbLong Or _
          iFieldType = dbCurrency Or _
          iFieldType = dbSingle Or _
          iFieldType = dbDouble _
          Then
          rst.MoveLast
          rst.MoveFirst

          a2dvGetSubsetFromQuery = rst.GetRows(rst.RecordCount)

      Else
          Dim aV(0 To 1, 0 To 1) As Variant
          aV(0, 0) = "Not Numeric"
          a2dvGetSubsetFromQuery = aV

      End If
  ElseIf sTest = "None" Then
      'don't do any testing
      rst.MoveLast
      rst.MoveFirst

      a2dvGetSubsetFromQuery = rst.GetRows(rst.RecordCount)
  Else
      MsgBox "Test type (sTest) can only be 'None' or 'Numeric'. It was: " & sTest
      Stop
  End If

  cleanup:
  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
  End Function
  Public Function GetOrOpenAndGetExcel() As Object
  'if excel is open it will return the excel object
  'if excel is not open it will open excel and return the excel object
  On Error GoTo 0
  On Error Resume Next
  Set GetOrOpenAndGetExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Set GetOrOpenAndGetExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0
  End Function
  ```

Edit1: The code I provide above is just to illustrate my attempt and the calculations. I'm pretty sure it isn't directly related to a good answer, but I'm not 100% sure. If I use what I have above, it produces one record at a time and I'd have to add (INSERT INTO) each record one at a time, which would be quite slow. My plan was to build a 2d array of the results and use that 2d array to add the records in batches, but was told that you can't do that without looping through the array adding each record once at a time, which would defeat the purpose. I am pretty sure a solution that includes looping through the fld1 types or one query with sub-queries that can do it in one step is the direction that should be taken. What I have done to optimize so far: I pulled the creation of the Excel object out so is created only once in the TestIt() Sub.

Edit2: I have 1305 fields to do calculations on. They are not all in the same table; however, for the purposes of this question I just need a working answer that does more than one field at a time. I.e. your answer can assume all fields are all in the same table and for simplicity your answer can include only 2 fields and I can expand it from there. In the code above I have calculated 12 metrics on one field "Rk-IU Mkt Cap" aggregating on one type,'Consumer Discretionary' ([GICS Sector] = 'Consumer Discretionary'"). What I have is not what I am after.

Comment: Hi, which approaches did you use so far in order to optimise your code?

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks. However, I don't think it is a matter of optimizing my code, but I don't know...

Comment: Does your input table really have 1035 columns? Can you upload sample database for testing?

Comment: I edited my question: see Edit2. You can just assume all of the fields are in one table and you can assume 2 or great fields instead of 1305. I just add the 1305 number in my question to emphasize the need for a speedy answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem so hard to do in MS Access.  If I have the logic right:

```
select "fld2" as factor, "fld1/"&fld1, #8/14/2015# as calcdate,
       sum(fld2), avg(fld2)
from table
group by fld1
union all
select "fld3" as factor, "fld1/"&fld1, #8/14/2015# as calcdate,
       sum(fld3), avg(fld3)
from table
group by fld1;
```

Comment: Just a little follow-up question on this: do you think I will have any limitations issues in MS Access if I build a query like this that has ~1305 select statements (one for each field I have to produce calculations on)? If not, what about ~20k selects (one for each field I have to produce continuations on times one for each aggregation type in fld1 for example)? If you aren't sure no worries. Just trying to save myself some time building some big queries! (Yes, we plan to outgrow MS Access soon.)

Comment: @mountainclimber . . . There is not an issue, per se, with building and running 1,305 different statements.  However, that is a lot of fields to have in a table, so there might be a better way to store the data.

Comment: I have discussed this many times in many forums and no one has a good solution so for now I am only keeping the calculated fields (sum, avg, etc. in the example above) and dropping the 1305 fields of raw data once the calcs are complete. Reason: 2000 tickers/companies, 1305 fully normalized fields for each ticker, and 12 or so calculated values per field, and 25 or so different aggregations of those fields to do these calcs on = either 2000 tables (one per ticker), or 1305 tables (one per field). Aka, too much. Happy to provide more info. Tell me where and I'll do it...

Comment: @mountainclimber . . . I suspect the fields are not fully normalized (first guess: some are a time series).  In any case, I would suggest that you move away from Access to another database.

Comment: we will move to a postgreSQL backend once we out grow access. Everything is normalized. We just store tons of data. (Quant finance)

Comment: FYI - you can see our schema in this question by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335579/ms-access-sql-retrieve-value-that-corresponds-to-x-days-back-relative-date

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work, just using pure tSql?

1: Create table and insert some sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FLD](
    [fld1] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [fld2] [int] NULL,
    [fld3] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT FLD VALUES ('a', 5, 9)
INSERT FLD VALUES ('b', 1, 8)
INSERT FLD VALUES ('a', 3, 7)
```

2: Use a nested [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to create the factors

```
SELECT t.factor,t.val + '/' + t.v  AS Agg, SUM(value) AS [Sum], AVG(value) AS [AVG]
FROM
(
    SELECT * from
    (
        select * from FLD f
        UNPIVOT
        (
            v
            for val in (fld1)
        ) piv
        ) f
    UNPIVOT 
    (
        value
        for factor in (fld2, fld3)
    ) s
) t 
group by t.v, t.factor, t.val
```

Comment: You can use a pass-through query and it does.

Comment: @mountainclimber - apologies, didn't realise you were using MS access. There's no unpivot solution in ms access sql, AFAIK, so my solution won't work. What is the end result for the data, i.e. do you have to use VBA?

Comment: Unfortunately I need it in VBA and/or SQL (that works in MS Access). Business requirement. Thank you for trying though...

Comment: Does it REALLY have to be in VBA, what I mean is can it be a VBA callout to an language designed for this stuff, e.g. R. If so you can link VBA to R - see here http://shashiasrblog.blogspot.ie/2013/10/vba-front-end-for-r.html for an example and implementing your requirement is pretty easy with R

Comment: I've used R extensively in the past and I have nothing but good things to say about it, but just not looking for an answer in R here (at this point).. Good thoughts though...thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**What you need is a pivot table.**

You have two alternatives:

### Migrate to SQL Server

This is the preferred method, then you could use `T-SQL` like @Johnv2020 suggested.

To read more about `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` in sql server, [click here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)

### Access/Excel Pivot table

I am personally more familar with Excel's  pivot table, but it seems that access has the same concept as well ([see here](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-views-in-a-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752)).

The desired result of your code, is basically running *several* pivot tables on the same data, with different aggregations (average,sum,...) and this could be done by automating pivot tables with `VBA` macros

Comment: You can do more or less the same thing with filters in Excel, but that and the pivot tables are too slow. Already tried that. Looking for an MS Access/SQL/VBA answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a big hot mess for the Access database engine to handle.  It's only going to get worse your data set grows.  I'd recommend getting the free version of SQL Server Express and using Access only as the front end interface.  Then as you grow, you can move all your databases to SQL Server... it's a much more robust database engine.  You'll be glad you learned it now.

[SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx)

If you go this route, you can do this all entirely with T-SQL and with a completely set based approach.  The speedup will be drastic.  I can't give you all the details here, but in general this is what you would need to do.  Online docs and Google can help you complete each step:

1. Install SQL Sever Express
2. Create a database
3. Migrate your data from the access tables to your database.
4. Create a stored procedure to update your aggregate table. (see below)
5. If you want an access front end... i would recommend creating a new ADP (access project file) and connect it to your SQL Server database.  You will be able to create forms and reports based off your SQL Server tables and run procedures on it.  But you can also just use a standard access project and use pass-though queries to get data or run procedures.

The procedure to insert data into your aggregate table would be easier if you changed your first table structure to look something like:

```
+------+------+------+
| fld1 |fname | fval |
+------+------+------+
| a    | fld2 |    5 |
| a    | fld2 |    8 |
| b    | fld2 |    5 |
| b    | fld2 |    2 |
| b    | fld2 |    1 |
| c    | fld2 |    6 |
| c    | fld2 |    0 |
| a    | fld3 |    1 |
| a    | fld3 |    9 |
| b    | fld3 |    0 |
| b    | fld3 |    5 |
| b    | fld3 |    6 |
| c    | fld3 |    0 |
| c    | fld3 |    6 |
+------+------+------+
```

You might not want to change your base data table structure though; if not you can create a view as a big union query to output it in this format:

```
select fld1,
    'fld2' fname,
    fld2 fval
from OrigDataTable
union all
select fld1,
    'fld3' fname,
    fld3 fval
from OrigDataTable
union all
...etc
```

Then your query to insert the aggregate data would look something like:

```
insert into AggreateTable
select Fname, 
    fld1,
    CONVERT(date, getdate()) CalcDate,
    SUM(fval) sum,
    AVG(Fval) avg,
    ...etc.
from DataTable
Group by Fname, fld1
```

Here are some links to help with building the expressions for the aggregate functions:

- [Skewness and Kurtosis](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/skewness-and-kurtosis-part-1-t-sql-solution/)
- [Quantile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx)
- [Other SQL Server Aggregate Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

If you want to try this approach with Access these could be of help:

- [Calculating skewness of a data distribution in SQL in Access without an additional subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613873/calculating-skewness-of-a-data-distribution-in-sql-in-access-without-an-addition)
- [Median, Mode, Skewness, and Kurtosis in MS Access](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/2529/Median-Mode-Skewness-and-Kurtosis-in-MS-Access.html)

You might get something like this approach to work completely within access... but I really think it's going to be too much for access to handle... if not today sometime soon.

Comment: Thanks Brian. The plan is to move to a postgreSQL backend once we outgrow MS Access. Feel free to weight in on the merits of that plan. My research indicates that it is a good solid free approach. Although I'm still holding out for a VBA/MS Access/SQL answer here, thank you for the input!

Comment: The approach I outlined should work with any database back-end with variance in the details: Restructure your base input table, get your aggregate functions out of excel macros and use SQL aggregate functions, and move towards a set based approach.  I think it may even be possible in access, it's just that I think it's going to be outdated sooner than later.