# MS Access SQL: retrieve value that corresponds to x days back (relative date)

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to produce this report:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------+
|    Factor    | In Model |   Agg    | Stat | Days Back |  HistValue  |  CurValue   |   % Change   | Threshold | Difference  | Flag |
+--------------+----------+----------+------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------+
| AFactorName2 |          | AggName1 | SD   |         1 | 13.08037943 | 12.98701299 | -0.0071379   |         1 | 0.9928621   |      |
| AFactorName2 |          | AggName2 | Mean |         5 | 13.28671329 | 12.98701299 | -0.022556391 |         2 | 2.977443609 | X    |
| AFactorName2 |        1 | AggName3 | NA%  |        20 | 13.01745636 | 12.98701299 | -0.002338658 |         3 | 2.997661342 |      |
| AFactorName3 |          | AggName1 | Mean |         1 | 25.67212895 | 25.63664308 | -0.001382272 |         1 | 0.998617728 |      |
| etc…         |          |          |      |           |             |             |              |           |             |      |
+--------------+----------+----------+------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------+
```

From these relationships:
[image: my schema]

Explanation of table above:
 - Factor -> just the name of the item that was being cal
 - InModel -> An MS Access Yes/No field (sort of a boolean)
 - Agg -> just the name of the aggregation previously used to produce the calcs (there is no aggregation in this question)
 - Stat -> the name of the calc previously used 
 - Days Back -> the number of days back used to find the HistValue 
 - HistValue -> the value the corresponds to the Days Back field relatively speaking. Ex: if Days Back = 1 then HistValue will be yesterday's value
 - CurValue -> the value that corresponds to today's date
 - % Change -> the change on a percentage basis that the values changed from HistValue to CurValue. Like this: ((CurValue/HistValue) - 1) * 100
 - Threshold -> This is a percentage (1 = 1%). 
 - Difference -> CurValue - HistValue = Difference. This is a display only value. It is not used anywhere currently. 
 - Flag -> This is the ultimate goal of this Flags report. It should have a value ("x" or 1 or "Flag" or whatever...) if Abs(% Change) >= Threshold, Flag = "x", else Flag = NULL.

Notes:

- I know there is a lot to do here, but **my main questions is: how to retrieve a value that corresponds to a certain number of days back (relative date). The historical values are stored in tbl_D1TsAggHistStats. IMPORTANT!: I want to retrieve the value that corresponds to the date that either is the date I am looking for or if that date isn't there get the next older value (never retrieve a value that is more recent than the date designated by the Days Back). For exmaple, if Days Back = 1 then get yesterday's value. If that value doesn't exist get the previous value.** If you answer this question you will get credit.
- Looking for a query that will do this in MS Access, sorry business requirement.
- I am thinking I need to do some time series indexing stuff to make this happen. I am willing to do this, but I need to know what to do exactly. Right now my tbl_CalcDates are sort of randomly populated (random gaps etc.) so it seems like there needs to be some date math done to find the best date and adjust what date/value to get if it is not there. Maybe order the dates in the table to make this easier?
- **A simplified example using simplified sample tables might be easier and it would be okay with me.**
- I got stuck on the HistVal part, but this is where I am at right now:

---

```
SELECT 
  f.factor, 
  f.usedinmodelranknow as InModel, 
  a.Agg, 
  sn.StatName, 
  hss.[Days Back], 
  (SELECT ...more stuff here...) AS HistVal,
  ...more stuff here...
FROM 
  tbl_CalcDates AS cd, 
  tbl_D1TsAggHistStats AS ts, 
  tbl_StatsNames AS sn, 
  tbl_Factors AS f, 
  tbl_HistStatsSettings AS hss, 
  tbl_Agg AS a
WHERE 
  f.pid_Factors = hss.FactorsID AND 
  sn.pid_StatsNames = hss.StatsNamesID AND 
  a.pid_Agg = hss.AggID AND 
  a.pid_Agg = hss.AggID AND 
  ts.FactorsID = f.pid_Factors AND 
  cd.pid_CalcDates = ts.CalcDatesID;
```

Thanks!

PS - I've since started an answer below. See that for my latest.

Comment: Could [DateAdd](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19) be useful here?

Comment: Can I use that in a query? I'm trying to do this in MS Access SQL. Or maybe I am not following you.

Comment: Yes, you can use `DateAdd` in a query.  Here is an example which returns yesterday's date: `SELECT DateAdd('d', -1, Date())`

Comment: Interesting, I will keep that in mind. Maybe in combination with Bulat's answer below...

Comment: you have a.pid_Agg = hss.AggID  in your WHERE clause twice, you need to change one of them to a.pid_agg = ts.aggID

Comment: Thanks. See my answer below please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table has ID field and you want to get the latest record before a given date, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t
WHERE 
  t.date <= @TargetDate AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable 
              WHERE id != t.id
                    AND date < t.date 
                    AND date <= @TargetDate)
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM myTable t
 WHERE 
      t.id IN (SELECT TOP 1 id 
               FROM myTable 
               WHERE date <= @TargetDate
               ORDER BY date DESC)
```

Comment: how do I create @TargetDate in MS Access SQL?

Comment: that is your parameter, it can be hardcoded or passed to the query.

Comment: In the first part of this answer, could someone explain when id != t.id   (i.e. when id will not equal id) in the same table (myTable)? That doesn't make sense to me. Is there suppose to be two tables or just one (myTable)?

Comment: It is just one table physically, but in the execution they will be treated as two sets hence alias is needed

Comment: Okay, I got the first one to work on my tbl_CalcDates table, but it doesn't work as expected. I have dates from 8/18/2015 through 9/15/2015. I make the target date 9/15/2015 and it returns the first date (8/18/2015). It should return 9/15/2015 since that date is in tbl_CalcDates. Here is the query I am using (!= is not allowed): SELECT * FROM  tbl_CalcDates AS cd
WHERE cd.CalcDate <= #9/15/2015#
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_CalcDates
              WHERE pid_CalcDates <> cd.pid_CalcDates
                    AND CalcDate < cd.CalcDate 
                    AND CalcDate <= #9/15/2015#);

Comment: Any reason I shouldn't use this? SELECT TOP 1 * FROM  tbl_CalcDates AS cd
WHERE cd.CalcDate <= #9/15/2015#
ORDER BY cd.CalcDate DESC

Comment: can you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/  (MS SQL Server version) otherwise it is impossible to understand what you are trying exactly and what does not work.

Comment: Oh, its okay. I am just giving feedback on your answer for you and for others. You don't have to fix it if you don't want. I'm getting things sorted out. See my answer. Creating the sqlfiddle is no small task for me (and newbie to this) so I'll pass.

Comment: SELECT TOP 1   does not always guarantee which row will be returned when used in a sub query.  You are better using he MAX method I used.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using sub-queries in the FROM statement to produce two temporary "tables" (not really, but that is how I think of it as a newbie SQL'er). Put another way, a query on two sub-query results in the FROM statement.

**Edited (9/16/15):**

```
    SELECT 
   Q1.factor, 
   Q1.Agg, 
   Q1.UsedInModelRankNow, 
   Q1.CalcDate AS Cur_Date,   
   Q2.CalcDate AS Past_Date1,
   DateDiff('d',Q1.CalcDate , Q2.CalcDate) AS Days_Back1,
   Q3.CalcDate AS Past_Date2,
   DateDiff('d',Q1.CalcDate , Q3.CalcDate) AS Days_Back2,
 Q1.NaPct AS Cur_NaPct, 
   Q2.NaPct AS Past_NaPct1,
   IIf(Q2.NaPct <> 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0,((Q1.NaPct - Q2.NaPct)/Abs(Q2.NaPct)) ,IIf(Q2.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct = 0,0,IIf(Q2.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0, ((Q1.NaPct - Q2.NaPct)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [NaPct_Chg%1],  
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.NaPct <> 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0,((Q1.NaPct - Q2.NaPct)/Abs(Q2.NaPct)) ,IIf(Q2.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct = 0,0,IIf(Q2.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0, ((Q1.NaPct - Q2.NaPct)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS NaPct_Flag1,
   Q3.NaPct AS Past_NaPct2,    
   IIf(Q3.NaPct <> 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0,((Q1.NaPct - Q3.NaPct)/Abs(Q3.NaPct)) ,IIf(Q3.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct = 0,0,IIf(Q3.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0, ((Q1.NaPct - Q3.NaPct)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [NaPct_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.NaPct <> 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0,((Q1.NaPct - Q3.NaPct)/Abs(Q3.NaPct)) ,IIf(Q3.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct = 0,0,IIf(Q3.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0, ((Q1.NaPct - Q3.NaPct)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS NaPct_Flag2,
 Q1.Mean AS Cur_Mean, 
   Q2.Mean AS Past_Mean1,  
   IIf(Q2.Mean <> 0 AND Q1.Mean <> 0,((Q1.Mean - Q2.Mean)/Abs(Q2.Mean)) ,IIf(Q2.Mean = 0 AND Q1.Mean = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Mean = 0 AND Q1.Mean <> 0, ((Q1.Mean - Q2.Mean)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Mean_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Mean <> 0 AND Q1.Mean <> 0,((Q1.Mean - Q2.Mean)/Abs(Q2.Mean)) ,IIf(Q2.Mean = 0 AND Q1.Mean = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Mean = 0 AND Q1.Mean <> 0, ((Q1.Mean - Q2.Mean)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Mean_Flag1, 
   Q3.Mean AS Past_Mean2, 
   IIf(Q3.Mean <> 0 AND Q1.Mean <> 0,((Q1.Mean - Q3.Mean)/Abs(Q3.Mean)) ,IIf(Q3.Mean = 0 AND Q1.Mean = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Mean = 0 AND Q1.Mean <> 0, ((Q1.Mean - Q3.Mean)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Mean_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Mean <> 0 AND Q1.Mean <> 0,((Q1.Mean - Q3.Mean)/Abs(Q3.Mean)) ,IIf(Q3.Mean = 0 AND Q1.Mean = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Mean = 0 AND Q1.Mean <> 0, ((Q1.Mean - Q3.Mean)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Mean_Flag2,
Q1.Sd AS Cur_Sd, 
   Q2.Sd AS Past_Sd1,  
   IIf(Q2.Sd <> 0 AND Q1.Sd <> 0,((Q1.Sd - Q2.Sd)/Abs(Q2.Sd)) ,IIf(Q2.Sd = 0 AND Q1.Sd = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Sd = 0 AND Q1.Sd <> 0, ((Q1.Sd - Q2.Sd)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Sd_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Sd <> 0 AND Q1.Sd <> 0,((Q1.Sd - Q2.Sd)/Abs(Q2.Sd)) ,IIf(Q2.Sd = 0 AND Q1.Sd = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Sd = 0 AND Q1.Sd <> 0, ((Q1.Sd - Q2.Sd)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Sd_Flag1, 
   Q3.Sd AS Past_Sd2, 
   IIf(Q3.Sd <> 0 AND Q1.Sd <> 0,((Q1.Sd - Q3.Sd)/Abs(Q3.Sd)) ,IIf(Q3.Sd = 0 AND Q1.Sd = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Sd = 0 AND Q1.Sd <> 0, ((Q1.Sd - Q3.Sd)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Sd_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Sd <> 0 AND Q1.Sd <> 0,((Q1.Sd - Q3.Sd)/Abs(Q3.Sd)) ,IIf(Q3.Sd = 0 AND Q1.Sd = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Sd = 0 AND Q1.Sd <> 0, ((Q1.Sd - Q3.Sd)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Sd_Flag2,
Q1.Low AS Cur_Low, 
   Q2.Low AS Past_Low1,  
   IIf(Q2.Low <> 0 AND Q1.Low <> 0,((Q1.Low - Q2.Low)/Abs(Q2.Low)) ,IIf(Q2.Low = 0 AND Q1.Low = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Low = 0 AND Q1.Low <> 0, ((Q1.Low - Q2.Low)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Low_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Low <> 0 AND Q1.Low <> 0,((Q1.Low - Q2.Low)/Abs(Q2.Low)) ,IIf(Q2.Low = 0 AND Q1.Low = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Low = 0 AND Q1.Low <> 0, ((Q1.Low - Q2.Low)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Low_Flag1, 
   Q3.Low AS Past_Low2, 
   IIf(Q3.Low <> 0 AND Q1.Low <> 0,((Q1.Low - Q3.Low)/Abs(Q3.Low)) ,IIf(Q3.Low = 0 AND Q1.Low = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Low = 0 AND Q1.Low <> 0, ((Q1.Low - Q3.Low)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Low_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Low <> 0 AND Q1.Low <> 0,((Q1.Low - Q3.Low)/Abs(Q3.Low)) ,IIf(Q3.Low = 0 AND Q1.Low = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Low = 0 AND Q1.Low <> 0, ((Q1.Low - Q3.Low)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Low_Flag2,
Q1.Q1 AS Cur_Q1, 
   Q2.Q1 AS Past_Q11,  
   IIf(Q2.Q1 <> 0 AND Q1.Q1 <> 0,((Q1.Q1 - Q2.Q1)/Abs(Q2.Q1)) ,IIf(Q2.Q1 = 0 AND Q1.Q1 = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Q1 = 0 AND Q1.Q1 <> 0, ((Q1.Q1 - Q2.Q1)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Q1_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Q1 <> 0 AND Q1.Q1 <> 0,((Q1.Q1 - Q2.Q1)/Abs(Q2.Q1)) ,IIf(Q2.Q1 = 0 AND Q1.Q1 = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Q1 = 0 AND Q1.Q1 <> 0, ((Q1.Q1 - Q2.Q1)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Q1_Flag1, 
   Q3.Q1 AS Past_Q12, 
   IIf(Q3.Q1 <> 0 AND Q1.Q1 <> 0,((Q1.Q1 - Q3.Q1)/Abs(Q3.Q1)) ,IIf(Q3.Q1 = 0 AND Q1.Q1 = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Q1 = 0 AND Q1.Q1 <> 0, ((Q1.Q1 - Q3.Q1)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Q1_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Q1 <> 0 AND Q1.Q1 <> 0,((Q1.Q1 - Q3.Q1)/Abs(Q3.Q1)) ,IIf(Q3.Q1 = 0 AND Q1.Q1 = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Q1 = 0 AND Q1.Q1 <> 0, ((Q1.Q1 - Q3.Q1)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Q1_Flag2,
Q1.Median AS Cur_Median, 
   Q2.Median AS Past_Median1,  
   IIf(Q2.Median <> 0 AND Q1.Median <> 0,((Q1.Median - Q2.Median)/Abs(Q2.Median)) ,IIf(Q2.Median = 0 AND Q1.Median = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Median = 0 AND Q1.Median <> 0, ((Q1.Median - Q2.Median)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Median_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Median <> 0 AND Q1.Median <> 0,((Q1.Median - Q2.Median)/Abs(Q2.Median)) ,IIf(Q2.Median = 0 AND Q1.Median = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Median = 0 AND Q1.Median <> 0, ((Q1.Median - Q2.Median)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Median_Flag1, 
   Q3.Median AS Past_Median2, 
   IIf(Q3.Median <> 0 AND Q1.Median <> 0,((Q1.Median - Q3.Median)/Abs(Q3.Median)) ,IIf(Q3.Median = 0 AND Q1.Median = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Median = 0 AND Q1.Median <> 0, ((Q1.Median - Q3.Median)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Median_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Median <> 0 AND Q1.Median <> 0,((Q1.Median - Q3.Median)/Abs(Q3.Median)) ,IIf(Q3.Median = 0 AND Q1.Median = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Median = 0 AND Q1.Median <> 0, ((Q1.Median - Q3.Median)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Median_Flag2,
Q1.Q3 AS Cur_Q3, 
   Q2.Q3 AS Past_Q31,  
   IIf(Q2.Q3 <> 0 AND Q1.Q3 <> 0,((Q1.Q3 - Q2.Q3)/Abs(Q2.Q3)) ,IIf(Q2.Q3 = 0 AND Q1.Q3 = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Q3 = 0 AND Q1.Q3 <> 0, ((Q1.Q3 - Q2.Q3)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Q3_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Q3 <> 0 AND Q1.Q3 <> 0,((Q1.Q3 - Q2.Q3)/Abs(Q2.Q3)) ,IIf(Q2.Q3 = 0 AND Q1.Q3 = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Q3 = 0 AND Q1.Q3 <> 0, ((Q1.Q3 - Q2.Q3)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Q3_Flag1, 
   Q3.Q3 AS Past_Q32, 
   IIf(Q3.Q3 <> 0 AND Q1.Q3 <> 0,((Q1.Q3 - Q3.Q3)/Abs(Q3.Q3)) ,IIf(Q3.Q3 = 0 AND Q1.Q3 = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Q3 = 0 AND Q1.Q3 <> 0, ((Q1.Q3 - Q3.Q3)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Q3_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Q3 <> 0 AND Q1.Q3 <> 0,((Q1.Q3 - Q3.Q3)/Abs(Q3.Q3)) ,IIf(Q3.Q3 = 0 AND Q1.Q3 = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Q3 = 0 AND Q1.Q3 <> 0, ((Q1.Q3 - Q3.Q3)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Q3_Flag2,
Q1.High AS Cur_High, 
   Q2.High AS Past_High1,  
   IIf(Q2.High <> 0 AND Q1.High <> 0,((Q1.High - Q2.High)/Abs(Q2.High)) ,IIf(Q2.High = 0 AND Q1.High = 0,0,IIf(Q2.High = 0 AND Q1.High <> 0, ((Q1.High - Q2.High)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [High_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.High <> 0 AND Q1.High <> 0,((Q1.High - Q2.High)/Abs(Q2.High)) ,IIf(Q2.High = 0 AND Q1.High = 0,0,IIf(Q2.High = 0 AND Q1.High <> 0, ((Q1.High - Q2.High)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS High_Flag1, 
   Q3.High AS Past_High2, 
   IIf(Q3.High <> 0 AND Q1.High <> 0,((Q1.High - Q3.High)/Abs(Q3.High)) ,IIf(Q3.High = 0 AND Q1.High = 0,0,IIf(Q3.High = 0 AND Q1.High <> 0, ((Q1.High - Q3.High)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [High_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.High <> 0 AND Q1.High <> 0,((Q1.High - Q3.High)/Abs(Q3.High)) ,IIf(Q3.High = 0 AND Q1.High = 0,0,IIf(Q3.High = 0 AND Q1.High <> 0, ((Q1.High - Q3.High)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS High_Flag2,
Q1.IQR AS Cur_IQR,
   Q2.IQR AS Past_IQR1,  
   IIf(Q2.IQR <> 0 AND Q1.IQR <> 0,((Q1.IQR - Q2.IQR)/Abs(Q2.IQR)) ,IIf(Q2.IQR = 0 AND Q1.IQR = 0,0,IIf(Q2.IQR = 0 AND Q1.IQR <> 0, ((Q1.IQR - Q2.IQR)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [IQR_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.IQR <> 0 AND Q1.IQR <> 0,((Q1.IQR - Q2.IQR)/Abs(Q2.IQR)) ,IIf(Q2.IQR = 0 AND Q1.IQR = 0,0,IIf(Q2.IQR = 0 AND Q1.IQR <> 0, ((Q1.IQR - Q2.IQR)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS IQR_Flag1, 
   Q3.IQR AS Past_IQR2, 
   IIf(Q3.IQR <> 0 AND Q1.IQR <> 0,((Q1.IQR - Q3.IQR)/Abs(Q3.IQR)) ,IIf(Q3.IQR = 0 AND Q1.IQR = 0,0,IIf(Q3.IQR = 0 AND Q1.IQR <> 0, ((Q1.IQR - Q3.IQR)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [IQR_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.IQR <> 0 AND Q1.IQR <> 0,((Q1.IQR - Q3.IQR)/Abs(Q3.IQR)) ,IIf(Q3.IQR = 0 AND Q1.IQR = 0,0,IIf(Q3.IQR = 0 AND Q1.IQR <> 0, ((Q1.IQR - Q3.IQR)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS IQR_Flag2,
Q1.Kurt AS Cur_Kurt, 
   Q2.Kurt AS Past_Kurt1,  
   IIf(Q2.Kurt <> 0 AND Q1.Kurt <> 0,((Q1.Kurt - Q2.Kurt)/Abs(Q2.Kurt)) ,IIf(Q2.Kurt = 0 AND Q1.Kurt = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Kurt = 0 AND Q1.Kurt <> 0, ((Q1.Kurt - Q2.Kurt)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Kurt_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Kurt <> 0 AND Q1.Kurt <> 0,((Q1.Kurt - Q2.Kurt)/Abs(Q2.Kurt)) ,IIf(Q2.Kurt = 0 AND Q1.Kurt = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Kurt = 0 AND Q1.Kurt <> 0, ((Q1.Kurt - Q2.Kurt)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Kurt_Flag1, 
   Q3.Kurt AS Past_Kurt2, 
   IIf(Q3.Kurt <> 0 AND Q1.Kurt <> 0,((Q1.Kurt - Q3.Kurt)/Abs(Q3.Kurt)) ,IIf(Q3.Kurt = 0 AND Q1.Kurt = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Kurt = 0 AND Q1.Kurt <> 0, ((Q1.Kurt - Q3.Kurt)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Kurt_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Kurt <> 0 AND Q1.Kurt <> 0,((Q1.Kurt - Q3.Kurt)/Abs(Q3.Kurt)) ,IIf(Q3.Kurt = 0 AND Q1.Kurt = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Kurt = 0 AND Q1.Kurt <> 0, ((Q1.Kurt - Q3.Kurt)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Kurt_Flag2,
Q1.Skew AS Cur_Skew, 
   Q2.Skew AS Past_Skew1,  
   IIf(Q2.Skew <> 0 AND Q1.Skew <> 0,((Q1.Skew - Q2.Skew)/Abs(Q2.Skew)) ,IIf(Q2.Skew = 0 AND Q1.Skew = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Skew = 0 AND Q1.Skew <> 0, ((Q1.Skew - Q2.Skew)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Skew_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Skew <> 0 AND Q1.Skew <> 0,((Q1.Skew - Q2.Skew)/Abs(Q2.Skew)) ,IIf(Q2.Skew = 0 AND Q1.Skew = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Skew = 0 AND Q1.Skew <> 0, ((Q1.Skew - Q2.Skew)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Skew_Flag1, 
   Q3.Skew AS Past_Skew2, 
   IIf(Q3.Skew <> 0 AND Q1.Skew <> 0,((Q1.Skew - Q3.Skew)/Abs(Q3.Skew)) ,IIf(Q3.Skew = 0 AND Q1.Skew = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Skew = 0 AND Q1.Skew <> 0, ((Q1.Skew - Q3.Skew)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Skew_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Skew <> 0 AND Q1.Skew <> 0,((Q1.Skew - Q3.Skew)/Abs(Q3.Skew)) ,IIf(Q3.Skew = 0 AND Q1.Skew = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Skew = 0 AND Q1.Skew <> 0, ((Q1.Skew - Q3.Skew)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Skew_Flag2,
Q1.Obs AS Cur_Obs, 
   Q2.Obs AS Past_Obs1,  
   IIf(Q2.Obs <> 0 AND Q1.Obs <> 0,((Q1.Obs - Q2.Obs)/Abs(Q2.Obs)) ,IIf(Q2.Obs = 0 AND Q1.Obs = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Obs = 0 AND Q1.Obs <> 0, ((Q1.Obs - Q2.Obs)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Obs_Chg%1], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q2.Obs <> 0 AND Q1.Obs <> 0,((Q1.Obs - Q2.Obs)/Abs(Q2.Obs)) ,IIf(Q2.Obs = 0 AND Q1.Obs = 0,0,IIf(Q2.Obs = 0 AND Q1.Obs <> 0, ((Q1.Obs - Q2.Obs)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Obs_Flag1, 
   Q3.Obs AS Past_Obs2, 
   IIf(Q3.Obs <> 0 AND Q1.Obs <> 0,((Q1.Obs - Q3.Obs)/Abs(Q3.Obs)) ,IIf(Q3.Obs = 0 AND Q1.Obs = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Obs = 0 AND Q1.Obs <> 0, ((Q1.Obs - Q3.Obs)/0.000000001))))*100 AS [Obs_Chg%2], 
   IIf(Abs(IIf(Q3.Obs <> 0 AND Q1.Obs <> 0,((Q1.Obs - Q3.Obs)/Abs(Q3.Obs)) ,IIf(Q3.Obs = 0 AND Q1.Obs = 0,0,IIf(Q3.Obs = 0 AND Q1.Obs <> 0, ((Q1.Obs - Q3.Obs)/0.000000001))))*100) > 3,"x",NULL) AS Obs_Flag2
FROM (SELECT *
     FROM tbl_HistStatsSettings AS hss, tbl_Agg AS a, tbl_Factors AS f, tbl_Statsnames AS sn, tbl_D1TsAggHistStats AS ts, tbl_CalcDates AS cd
     WHERE hss.[Days Back]=0
       AND f.pid_Factors=hss.FactorsID
       AND sn.pid_StatsNames =hss.StatsNamesID
       AND a.pid_Agg=hss.AggID
       AND ts.FactorsID=f.pid_Factors
       AND ts.AggID=a.pid_Agg
       AND ts.CalcDatesID=cd.pid_CalcDates
       AND cd.CalcDate =(SELECT TOP 1 CalcDate FROM  tbl_CalcDates
                                          WHERE CalcDate <= DateAdd('d', -1,Date())
                                          ORDER BY CalcDate DESC))  AS Q1, 
    (SELECT *
     FROM tbl_HistStatsSettings AS hss, tbl_Agg AS a, tbl_Factors AS f, tbl_Statsnames AS sn, tbl_D1TsAggHistStats AS ts, tbl_CalcDates AS cd
     WHERE hss.[Days Back]=0
       AND f.pid_Factors=hss.FactorsID
       AND sn.pid_StatsNames =hss.StatsNamesID
       AND a.pid_Agg=hss.AggID
       AND ts.FactorsID=f.pid_Factors
       AND ts.AggID=a.pid_Agg
       AND ts.CalcDatesID=cd.pid_CalcDates
       AND cd.CalcDate = (SELECT TOP 1 CalcDate FROM  tbl_CalcDates
                                          WHERE CalcDate <= DateAdd('d', -2,Date())
                                          ORDER BY CalcDate DESC) ) AS Q2, 
     (SELECT *
     FROM tbl_HistStatsSettings AS hss, tbl_Agg AS a, tbl_Factors AS f, tbl_Statsnames AS sn, tbl_D1TsAggHistStats AS ts, tbl_CalcDates AS cd
     WHERE hss.[Days Back]=0
       AND f.pid_Factors=hss.FactorsID
       AND sn.pid_StatsNames =hss.StatsNamesID
       AND a.pid_Agg=hss.AggID
       AND ts.FactorsID=f.pid_Factors
       AND ts.AggID=a.pid_Agg
       AND ts.CalcDatesID=cd.pid_CalcDates
       AND cd.CalcDate = (SELECT TOP 1 CalcDate FROM  tbl_CalcDates
                                          WHERE CalcDate <= DateAdd('d', -7,Date())
                                          ORDER BY CalcDate DESC) )  AS Q3
WHERE Q1.factor = Q2.factor
   AND Q3.factor = Q2.factor
   AND Q1.Agg = Q2.Agg
   AND Q3.Agg = Q2.Agg
   AND Q1.StatName = Q2.StatName
   AND Q3.StatName = Q2.StatName
   AND Q1.[Days Back]=0
   AND Q1.CalcDate = (SELECT TOP 1 CalcDate FROM  tbl_CalcDates
                                          WHERE CalcDate <= DateAdd('d', -1,Date())
                                          ORDER BY CalcDate DESC)
   AND  Q1.StatName = "NaPct"
   AND Q1.Agg IN (SELECT Agg FROM tbl_Agg)
```

In the end it is not what I asked for in the OP, but its getting there. I will edit/add as I sort out the rest. If someone has a better solution, please post it and I'll give you credit.

Comment: it looks like you always want to subtract 1 day, 2 days, and 7 days from CalcDate.  Consider creating a query on your tbl_D1TsAggHistStats table with 3 additional fields, calcDate_dateBack1, calcDate_dateBack2, and calcDate_dateBack7.  Then use that query instead of your base table in your calculations.

Comment: I think I follow you. Actually, I have the real days back values I want in table tbl_HistStatsSettings. I plan to pull those in and use them. Once I sort out how to do it, I'll edit my answer again with the change. I also have the threshold of 3 in the select that needs to come from the settings table as well. Still sorting out how to do it. Will post. Help welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to understand your schema, but I can see that the technique I outline below will be helpful.  (It uses an easily understandable schema of one table, you will need to adapt it for your needs).

The SQL below gets the most recent orderdate for product 1 prior to the date given - and provides the order ID,

```
SELECT ProductID
     , MAX(OrderDate)  AS MAXOrderDate
FROM myOrders 
WHERE 
  OrderDate <= @TargetDate 
  AND ProductID = 1
```

You could use the above as a sub query with the main query getting the details of the previous order.

Mainorders.* has the details of the previous order (which may be on the same date or earlier than than main order, but not the same order)

```
SELECT Mainorders.*
FROM myOrders AS Mainorders
     INNER JOIN 
     (
      SELECT Io.ProductID
           , Io.MAX(OrderDate)  AS MAXOrderDate
      FROM myOrders AS Io
      WHERE Io.OrderDate <= Mainorders.OrderDate   
        AND IO.OrderID <> Mainorders.OrderID
     ) as LastOrder
     ON ( LastOrder.ProductID = Mainorders.ProductID
          AND  LastOrder.MAXOrderDate = Mainorders.OrderDate
WHERE Mainorders.ProductID = 1
  AND Mainorders.OrderDate = 1/1/2015
```

You can then use the above to get hat you need.

In access, create a named query (called qryselGetLastOrder) with the above SQL text but without the WHERE clause.

The create another query that uses the above named query

Orders.* gives the most recent order
qryselGetLastOrder.* gives the details of the last order for the same product

```
SELECT Orders.* , qryselGetLastOrder.*
FROM myOrders AS Orders
     LEFT JOIN qryselGetLastOrder      
     ON ( Orders.ProductID = qryselGetLastOrder.ProductID )

' Note that the 
' left join will also cause products
' that have only been ordered once to be included
```

Comment: What is it about my schema that makes it difficult to understand? Am I doing anything that is non-standard in terms of the structure? I know it is not enterprise data in the traditional sense, but besides that (which I can't do anything about).

Comment: Your schema is fine.  I can see it's well named and structured, but it's a lot more complicated than my single schema, so for simplicities sakes I've used the one table.  If you were to adapt the technique I presented above, you queries would look a lot more complex (which would be hard to learn from in an example)

Comment: While I can appreciate what you are saying, I think some people would appreciate knowing how to overcome the complexity. I know it would have helped me a lot.

Comment: If I spent ages looking at your schema, I would  generate very complex code that you would not be able to learn from.  Try to incorporate the ideas into your own schema  (ie queries will have many tabels joiend together.) it will work if yuo stick at it./  Give it a go so i can see whetehr yo understood what I wrote).

Comment: I have an answer going here already, but I took a different route. Let me know what you think if you have the time. Thanks for time already spent!

Answer (score 0):

I gave myself 15mins to help you... so here's some inspiration...
There's quite a lot of changes you can make and a few more I've not listed, but try to get the code working using the principals I've outlined here and I may be able to help you more.

(I recommend using Notepad++ ( a fee editor as it will help you line up the brackets!)

```
' First created this as a seperate query named "MyQuery1"
(SELECT hss.*, a.*, f.*, sn.*, ts,*, cd.*    '' Use only the columsn you need (to speed it up)
      , Periods.*
     FROM tbl_HistStatsSettings AS hss
        , tbl_Agg AS a
        , tbl_Factors AS f
        , tbl_Statsnames AS sn
        , tbl_D1TsAggHistStats AS ts
        , tbl_CalcDates AS cd
        , (SELECT iif(CalcDate<=Date()-7,"Q3", iif(CalcDate<=Date()-2,"Q2",iif(CalcDate<=Date()-1,"Q1","Other",))) AS ThePeriod
                , MAX(CalcDate) AS MaxDateInPeriod
             FROM  tbl_CalcDates
           GROUP BY iif(CalcDate<=Date()-7,"Q3", iif(CalcDate<=Date()-2,"Q2",iif(CalcDate<=Date()-1,"Q1","Other",)))
          ) AS Periods
     WHERE hss.[Days Back]=0
       AND f.pid_Factors=hss.FactorsID
       AND sn.pid_StatsNames =hss.StatsNamesID
       AND a.pid_Agg=hss.AggID
       AND ts.FactorsID=f.pid_Factors
       AND ts.AggID=a.pid_Agg
       AND ts.CalcDatesID=cd.pid_CalcDates
)     


' Now heres the main query that uses the above
' With better formatting - indenting of statements
' (I've removed some lines as it is repeatative)

   SELECT 
     Q1.factor
   , Q2.CalcDate AS Past_Date1
   , Q3.CalcDate AS Past_Date2

   , IIf( Q2.NaPct <> 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0
        , ((Q1.NaPct - Q2.NaPct)/Abs(Q2.NaPct)) 
        , IIf(Q2.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct = 0
             ,0
             ,IIf( Q2.NaPct = 0 AND Q1.NaPct <> 0
                 , ((Q1.NaPct - Q2.NaPct)/0.000000001)
                 )
             )
        )*100 
    AS [NaPct_Chg%1]

FROM  (  SELECT * FROM MyQuery1                               
         WHERE MyQuery1.CalcDate <= Periods.MaxDateInPeriod
           AND MyQuery1.ThePeriod = "Q1"
      ) AS Q1 
    , ( SELECT * FROM MyQuery1                                
         WHERE MyQuery1.CalcDate <= Periods.MaxDateInPeriod
           AND MyQuery1.ThePeriod = "Q2"
      ) AS Q2, 
    , ( SELECT * FROM MyQuery1                                
         WHERE MyQuery1.CalcDate <= Periods.MaxDateInPeriod
           AND MyQuery1.ThePeriod = "Q3"
      ) AS Q3 
WHERE Q1.factor = Q2.factor         ' You should be using outer joins (ie LEFT JOINS) and using the ON clause.
   AND Q3.factor = Q2.factor        ' AS your code only returns rows if teh is a row in Q1, Q2 and Q3.
   AND Q1.Agg = Q2.Agg
   AND Q3.Agg = Q2.Agg
   AND Q1.StatName = Q2.StatName
   AND Q3.StatName = Q2.StatName
   AND Q1.[Days Back]=0
   AND Q1.CalcDate = (SELECT TOP 1 CalcDate FROM  tbl_CalcDates
                                          WHERE CalcDate <= DateAdd('d', -1,Date())
                                          ORDER BY CalcDate DESC)
   AND  Q1.StatName = "NaPct"
   AND Q1.Agg IN (SELECT Agg FROM tbl_Agg)
```

Note that SOME of the IIF statements (or the conditions in the IIF statement)  in you own very long SELECT clause, could probably be moved into the MyQuery1 select clause (ie where the calc is the same of each period)

Comment: Thank you! It seems like Periods.* needs some explanation. Does that have something to do with getting the days back (rather than hardcoding it)?

Comment: Sorry, periods 6 have read theperiods, it's selecting all columns from the subquery

Comment: Is the alias name of a subquery defined in the from clause of the main query.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't follow. Could you change it in the code in your answer? Right now in Access I am getting a parameter value request for Periods.MaxDateInPeriod